# trying to get Qt4 example to run on ubuntu 10.10 with Qt Creator 4 installed

Tags: c++, qt-creator

```
#include "framecapture.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <QtWidget>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    if (argc != 3) {
        std::cout << "Capture a web page and save its internal frames in different images" << std::endl << std::endl;
        std::cout << "  framecapture <url> <outputfile>" << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Notes:" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "  'url' is the URL of the web page to be captured" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "  'outputfile' is the prefix of the image files to be generated" << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Example: " << std::endl;
        std::cout << "  framecapture qt.nokia.com trolltech.png" << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Result:" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "  trolltech.png (full page)" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "  trolltech_frame1.png (...) trolltech_frameN.png ('N' number of internal frames)" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    QUrl url = QUrl::fromUserInput(QString::fromLatin1(argv[1]));
    QString fileName = QString::fromLatin1(argv[2]);

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    FrameCapture capture;
    QObject::connect(&capture, SIGNAL(finished()), QApplication::instance(), SLOT(quit()));
    capture.load(url, fileName);

    return a.exec();
}
```

I get QtWidget file or directory not found. When I use QWidget, it will say

> /home/me/qtwebkit-examples-and-demos/examples/webkit/framecapture-build-desktop/../framecapture/main.cpp:68:
>   error: variable ‘QApplication a’ has initializer but incomplete type
>
> /home/me/qtwebkit-examples-and-demos/examples/webkit/framecapture-build-desktop/../framecapture/main.cpp:70:
>   error: incomplete type ‘QApplication’ used in nested name specifier

I don't know why none of the examples from **git://gitorious.org/+qt-developers/qt/qtwebkit-examples-and-demos-staging.git** is working. It always seems to complain about the #includes not finding the required components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will simply have to include QApplication. That is:

```
#include <QApplication>
```

If I'm not mistaken there is no such include file as `<QtWidget>` anyway. That should be `<QWidget>`. Given the specific example I would expect a general include of `<QtGui>` instead.

Comment: this worked but I am curiosu to why they are still using QtWidget and didn't bother to include QApplication. could it be that they are using an old version of Qt? Thank you!!

Comment: As I expected (and stated in my answer) the file actually includes `<QtGui>` and not `<QtWidget>`, as you have in your answer above. (I have gotten the sources from the git you link to just now). So either they changed it recently or you edited it. Including QtGui will include all relevant files, so should work just fine.